# Rails form tag not going to custom delete route, going to standard delete route instead

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I am trying to delete a collection of items based upon checkboxes. I created a custom route. The destroy_multiple route.

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects do
    resources :lists, shallow: true do
      member do
        post :sort
      end
      resources :items, shallow: true
    end
  end

  resources :items do
    collection do
     delete :destroy_multiple, :as => :destroy_multiple
    end
  end
  resource :react
end
```

When I run rake routes I get this as a result

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                               Controller#Action
             sort_list POST   /lists/:id/sort(.:format)                 lists#sort
            list_items GET    /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)           items#index
                       POST   /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)           items#create
         new_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/new(.:format)       items#new
             edit_item GET    /items/:id/edit(.:format)                 items#edit
                  item GET    /items/:id(.:format)                      items#show
                       PATCH  /items/:id(.:format)                      items#update
                       PUT    /items/:id(.:format)                      items#update
                       DELETE /items/:id(.:format)                      items#destroy
         project_lists GET    /projects/:project_id/lists(.:format)     lists#index
                       POST   /projects/:project_id/lists(.:format)     lists#create
      new_project_list GET    /projects/:project_id/lists/new(.:format) lists#new
             edit_list GET    /lists/:id/edit(.:format)                 lists#edit
                  list GET    /lists/:id(.:format)                      lists#show
                       PATCH  /lists/:id(.:format)                      lists#update
                       PUT    /lists/:id(.:format)                      lists#update
                       DELETE /lists/:id(.:format)                      lists#destroy
              projects GET    /projects(.:format)                       projects#index
                       POST   /projects(.:format)                       projects#create
           new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                   projects#new
          edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)              projects#edit
               project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                   projects#show
                       PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                   projects#update
                       PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                   projects#update
                       DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                   projects#destroy
destroy_multiple_items DELETE /items/destroy_multiple(.:format)         items#destroy_multiple
                 items GET    /items(.:format)                          items#index
                       POST   /items(.:format)                          items#create
              new_item GET    /items/new(.:format)                      items#new
                       GET    /items/:id/edit(.:format)                 items#edit
                       GET    /items/:id(.:format)                      items#show
                       PATCH  /items/:id(.:format)                      items#update
                       PUT    /items/:id(.:format)                      items#update
                       DELETE /items/:id(.:format)                      items#destroy
                 react POST   /react(.:format)                          reacts#create
             new_react GET    /react/new(.:format)                      reacts#new
            edit_react GET    /react/edit(.:format)                     reacts#edit
                       GET    /react(.:format)                          reacts#show
                       PATCH  /react(.:format)                          reacts#update
                       PUT    /react(.:format)                          reacts#update
                       DELETE /react(.:format)                          reacts#destroy
```

And my form tag looks like this..

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'items', :action => 'destroy_multiple'), :method => 'delete' do %>

  <ul class="list-group sortable" data-update-url="<%= sort_list_path(list) %>">
    <%= render list.items %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag("Delete Items") %>
<% end %>
```

I am not getting any errors but it is not going to the right controller action it ends up at just the destroy action for a singular item. Here is my controller.
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

```
  before_action :set_item, only: [:edit, :update]

  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.create params[:item].permit(:content)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @item.update_attributes(params[:item].permit(:content))
  end

  def destroy
    @item.destroy
  end

  def destroy_multiple

    debugger
  end

  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.where(id: params[:id]).first!
  end

end
```

I just want the form submission to go to the custom destroy_multiple action. I appreciate any help. Thank You.

Comment: You declare your items resources 2 times. First time is inside lists, and second on its own. Try moving your custom delete route inside your nested item resource.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. You should edit your post to show the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per @JoshHumphrey my error was having multiple routes. My updated route file is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects do
    resources :lists, shallow: true do
      member do
        post :sort
      end
      resources :items, shallow: true do 
        collection do
           delete :destroy_multiple, :as => :destroy_multiple
        end 
      end
    end
  end


  resource :react
end
```

And I updated the form a bit to pass the list id down so here is the form

```
<%= form_tag(destroy_multiple_list_items_path(list_id: list.id),method: :delete,remote: true) do %>
  <ul class="list-group sortable" data-update-url="<%= sort_list_path(list) %>">
    <%= render list.items %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag("Delete Selected",  :class => "btn btn-warning") %>
<% end %>
```

Everything else stayed the same! Thanks for the help Josh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow, at first you create route like original `destroy` action

```
resources :items do
 collection do
   #delete :destroy_multiple, :as => :destroy_multiple
   delete '/destroy_multiple/:id(.:format)' => 'items#destroy_multiple', constraints: { id: /.*/ }, as: :destroy_multiple
  end
end
```

Now run `rake routes` you get the something like this (not tested route but code is right now)

```
destroy_multiple_items DELETE /items/destroy_multiple/:id(.:format)         items#destroy_multiple
```

Now you can try to delete using checkbox

```
def destroy_multiple
   Item.where(id: params[:id]).destroy_all
   # redirect
end
```

Hope to help